# Package latexalpha2 Error in Microsoft Visual Code

Tags: texworks, latexalpha2

When using package latexalpha2 in Microsoft Visual Code, it gives this error:

> Package latexalpha2: WolframScript cannot be found, which is required to use latexalpha2.

while the same code runs well when using Texworks.

(Wolfram Engine has already been installed and shell escape enabled.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{latexalpha2}
\begin{document}
MWE
\end{document}
```

Comment: This question could use a MWE that would include reproduction of the error stated.

Comment: WolframScript  is not in the path of the shell used by tex.  usually that  means it's been set locally but tex launched from an editor started from the desktop not using the user path